# Add a HTML element to the anchor tag if has child or sub menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I tried this

```
if ($('nav li.menu-item-has-children:has(ul)'))
$ ('nav li.menu-item-has-children a').append ( "<span class=\"plus-minus\">+</span>");
```

but all the anchor tags child menus are also getting the same HTML element Added

this is the menu structute

```
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item "><a href="home/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item" ><a href="about">About <span class=\"plus-minus\">+</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="basics/">Basic</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="products" aria-current="page">Products</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li  class="menu-item"><a href="Product-1">Product-1</a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item "><a href="Product-2">Product-2</a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item "><a href="Product-3">Product-3</a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item "><a href="Product-4">Product-4</a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item "><a href="Product-5">Product-5</a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item "><a href="Product-6">Product-6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li  class="menu-item"><a href="contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

i want it to be

```
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item "><a href="home/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item" ><a href="about">About <span class=\"plus-minus\">+</span> </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="basics/">Basic</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="products" aria-current="page">Products <span class=\"plus-minus\">+</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li  class="menu-item"><a href="Product-1">Product-1</a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item "><a href="Product-2">Product-2</a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item "><a href="Product-3">Product-3</a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item "><a href="Product-4">Product-4</a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item "><a href="Product-5">Product-5</a></li>
      <li  class="menu-item "><a href="Product-6">Product-6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li  class="menu-item"><a href="contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>


if ($('nav li.menu-item-has-children:has(ul)'))
$ ('nav li.menu-item-has-children a').append ( "<span class=\"plus-minus\">+</span>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("nav li.menu-item:has(ul)").length) {
      $("nav li.menu-item-has-children > a").append(
        '<span class="plus-minus">+</span>'
      );
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of those lines have incorrect semantics:

```
if ($('nav li.menu-item-has-children:has(ul)'))
```

The return value of the `$()` function would always be a jQuery object so the condition would always evaluate to `true`. You could do this instead

```
if ($('nav li.menu-item-has-children:has(ul)').length)
```

but hold on because it's unnecessary.

```
$ ('nav li.menu-item-has-children a').append ( "<span class=\"plus-minus\">+</span>");
```

appends the `<span>` element to all elements matching the selector. The `:has()` in the other line has no effect on that selector.

What I'm assuming you actually want is

```
$ ('nav li.menu-item-has-children:has(ul) a').append ( "<span class=\"plus-minus\">+</span>");
```

With no `if`. It would select all  elements which are descendants of `nav li.menu-item-has-children:has(ul)`, and append the `<span>` element to them.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are appending **span** element to every anchor tag under `li.menu-item-has-children` class.

Your can use `>` selector.

Try replacing this line.

```
$ ('nav li.menu-item-has-children > a').append ( "<span class=\"plus-minus\">+</span>");
```